# System.Drawing.dll does not follow after deploying the application using IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, dll, system.drawing

I have a System.Drawing.dll file that is from 2016 and for some strange reason this does not patch while deploying the application to the server via IIS.

I need evrey time to include this file manually after the deployment which happend times that I forgot and because of this some of my program dosent work as expeccted.

Im using .Net and c#

Comment: What do you expect to do with `System.Drawing` in a web app?

Comment: `System.Drawing` is not supported in web apps, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-most-common-technologies-not-supported-by-microsoft-8675c409bde2